# TranslateX every single transitionend

Tags: javascript

I want to make an animated transition of text at every `transitionend` event. Here is my code. The problem is that it does smooth translation only once after first `translationX`. I want to have this effect every single translation. Cheers.

```
sliderSlide1.addEventListener('transitionend',()=>{ 
  $(tekstowo1).text(nazwy[licz]);
  $(tekstowo1).css("transform","translateX(-100px)");
  $(tekstowo1).css("transition","transform 2s ease-in");
  $(tekstowo1).animate({opacity: 0},0);
  $(tekstowo1).animate({opacity: 1},1000);
```